# How to convert json to FoxPro cursor

Tags: json, visual-foxpro, foxpro

File contains invoice list in json format like:

```
{
    "status": "OK", "statusCode": 200, "messages": null,
    "data": [{
        "payment_type": "banktransfer", "fine": "0.200000", "quote_id": null, "order_id": null, "prepayment_id": null, "credited_invoices": [],
        "interested_party_address_id": 279, "project_id": 875, "currency": "EUR", "owner_id": 3, "date": "2019-03-15", "deadline": "2019-03-20",
    },

    {
        "payment_type": "banktransfer", "fine": "0.30000", "quote_id": null, "order_id": null, "prepayment_id": null, "credited_invoices": [],
        "interested_party_address_id": 79, "project_id": 85, "currency": "EUR", "owner_id": 3, "date": "2019-04-15", "deadline": "2019-43-20",
    }
    .... more same type elements
    ]
}
```

How to convert it to FoxPRo cursor ?
Cursor should contain payment_type, fine, quote_id etc columns.

I tried

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=qdfoxjson

and

http://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/blog/index.php/2008/12/19/visual-foxpro-json-class-update/

but it looks like they require json to be in different format than my json.

Andrus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is your JSON is invalid. There shouldn't be a hanging comma after the "deadline" date values.

The second thing is that there is no mechanism to tell VFP how to map elements to fields. So you have to do it yourself.

To do this I would use the [njJson](https://github.com/VFPX/nfJson) library, specifically `nfJsonRead`.

Assuming your JSON is in file 'test.json' and you have nfJsonRead.prg then for example:

```
    Close All
    Clear All
    Clear

    Set Procedure To nfJsonRead additive

    * -- Add the other fields as appropriate.
    Create Cursor mydata (payment_type c(20), fine n(12, 2))

    loJson = nfjsonread(FileToStr("test.json"))

    For each loData in loJson.data

        Insert into mydata values (loData.payment_type, Val(loData.fine))

    EndFor
```

Comment: I used `nfOpenJson( value, '$.array', mappings )` from library you referenced. It creates cursor and allows to specify mappings. Howerer date values from my sample json are empty in cursor, it looks like bug. Also it has `private all` statement which breaks my application.

Comment: The snippet from Alan is ok. A json date should be in format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS for nfjsonread to convert to datetime, or YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00 to convert to date type. Also, there's no way the private all  statement can "break you application" if you pass invalid json , nfJson will throw an error indicating the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick something I came up with for you.  If I had more stuff in similar format, I would have done some cursor/table structure of "looking for begin delimiter", "looking for end delimiter", "final data type", etc... then looping through for each part.  Here, I actually am showing how each part is being extracted and how to get one data row at a time.

```
** Example to put into a string called "json", no other context to json
TEXT TO json noshow
{
    "status": "OK", "statusCode": 200, "messages": null,
    "data": [{1
        "payment_type": "banktransfer", "fine": "0.200000", "quote_id": null, "order_id": null, "prepayment_id": null, "credited_invoices": [],
        "interested_party_address_id": 279, "project_id": 875, "currency": "EUR", "owner_id": 3, "date": "2019-03-15", "deadline": "2019-03-20",
    },

    {2
        "payment_type": "banktransfer", "fine": "0.30000", "quote_id": null, "order_id": null, "prepayment_id": null, "credited_invoices": [],
        "interested_party_address_id": 79, "project_id": 85, "currency": "EUR", "owner_id": 3, "date": "2019-04-15", "deadline": "2019-43-20",
    }
    .... more same type elements
    ]
}
ENDTEXT

** Strip the "Status" component ang get just the Data
json = SUBSTR( json, ATC( ["data":], json ))



CREATE CURSOR C_ImportRecs;
(   PayType c(20),;
    Fine    n(10,6),;
    QuoteID i,;
    OrderID i,;
    PrepayID i,;
    Invoices c(20),;
    IntPartyAddrID i,;
    ProjectID i,;
    TransCurrency c(3),;
    OwnerID i,;
    DatePart c(15),;
    TransDate d,;
    DeadPart c(15),;
    Deadline d )

** scatter all fields to an object which will have fields by same name  
SCATTER NAME newRec

** start counter to 1
nRow = 1
DO while .t.
    ** Look within the json string for the "nRow" instance of data starting / ending with { / }
    oneData = STREXTRACT( json, "{", "}", nRow )

    ** if no more entries, get out   
    IF EMPTY( ALLTRIM( oneData ))
        exit
    ENDIF 


    ** if memory variables are same name as cursor/table columns, simplifies insert
    newRec.PayType = STREXTRACT( oneData, ["payment_type": "], ["] )
    newRec.Fine = VAL( STREXTRACT( oneData, ["fine": "], ["] ))

    ** not including closing quote as ending delimiter since null allowed, looking for the "," after the IDs
    newRec.QuoteID = INT( VAL( STREXTRACT( oneData, ["quote_id": ], [,] ) ))
    newRec.OrderID = INT( VAL( STREXTRACT( oneData, ["order_id": ], [,] ) ))
    newRec.PrepayID = INT( VAL( STREXTRACT( oneData, ["prepayment_id": ], [,] ) ))

    newRec.Invoices = STREXTRACT( oneData, ["credited_invoices": ], [,] )

    newRec.IntPartyAddrID = INT( VAL( STREXTRACT( oneData, ["interested_party_address_id": ], [,] ) ))
    newRec.ProjectID = INT( VAL( STREXTRACT( oneData, ["project_id": ], [,] ) ))

    ** Currency is reserved word.
    newRec.TransCurrency = STREXTRACT( oneData, ["currency": "], ["] )

    newRec.OwnerID = INT( VAL( STREXTRACT( oneData, ["owner_id": ], [,] ) ))

    ** Date is reserved word
    newRec.DatePart = ""
    newRec.DatePart = STREXTRACT( oneData, ["date": "], ["] )

    ** Nice for macro substitution.  Take incoming date format of ex: "2019-03-15"
    ** and change to "2019,03,15"  This is because the DATE() function expects 
    ** 3 parameters for YEAR, MONTH, DAY
    tryDate = STRTRAN( newRec.DatePart, "-", "," )
    ** Now, by using macro via "&" forces the line below to immediately run as if
    ** run as if it was DATE( 2019,03,15) and create an actual date value
    TRY
        newRec.TransDate = DATE( &tryDate )
    CATCH
        newRec.TransDate = CTOD( "" )
    ENDTRY 

    ** same for deadline
    newRec.DeadPart = STREXTRACT( oneData, ["deadline": "], ["] )
    tryDate = STRTRAN( newRec.DeadPart, "-", "," )
    TRY
        ** your second record has a month 43 which is an invalid month
        newRec.Deadline = DATE( &tryDate )
    CATCH
        newRec.Deadline = CTOD( "" )
    ENDTRY 


    ** Since the cursor "C_ImportRecs" is already the active focus, 
    ** we can just insert from memory variables
    INSERT INTO C_ImportRecs FROM NAME newRec

    ** try if any more records
    nRow = nRow + 1
ENDDO


BROWSE NORMAL NOCAPTIONS NOWAIT
```

Comment: I  found `nfOpenJson( value, '$.array', mappings )` from nfJson libary. It creates cursor from json.